# lubuntu orangepi default root username and password?

Tags: ssh, lubuntu, password, raspberrypi

I just used win32 disk imager to put Lubuntu on my SD card, which I then plugged into my orange pi zero.  The orange pi zero has no video out, so you have to ssh into it. [I downloaded it from the orange pi website.](http://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/orangepizero/2016-11-08/orangepizero_6d2326f5d4f3ae42d103bb1.html)

I have successfully SSH'd in, and am at the point where it asks me to login.  I type in root, and I have tried many passwords, and I don't know which is correct, I keep getting "Access Denied".

Comment: I didn't find that, so thank you.

Comment: @mikewhatever: you should post that as an answer and then ping me so I can come back and upvote.

Comment: Why was it down voted? Never forget that even if answer is trivial to find, stackexchange makes it much more SEO-friendly so human queriable. For this very reason, it was worth asking (and if you feel lazy, then don't instead of down voting).

Answer (score 10):

I found this:

```
Lubuntu_1404_For_OrangePi_Zero_v0_8_0.img.xz
Version:     0.8.0
Release date:    2016-11-25
Release notes:  username(root/orangepi), password(orangepi)
```

Good luck with it

[link for reference](http://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/orangepizero/2016-11-08/orangepizero_6d2326f5d4f3ae42d103bb1.html)